Add clickable link on section title and section number
I want to create a PDF where each section heading has a link to the TOC that corresponds to that section.
I found an elegant solution to do this in this Stack Exchange question, but I want one additional thing. This solution does not generate a link to the section number, but I want both the section number and the section title text to have link to TOC.
Is there a good method to accomplish this? Thanks.
